# Show Spinner using ModalProgressHUD in Flutter whilst ListView.builder reads information from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a screen where I try to read all my documents as a list using a Listview.builder in Flutter. I want to use ModalProgressHUD to show circular spinner whilst data is read from Firebase. When it's done building, I want to stop showing circular spinner by setting showSpinner to false.

I can hack this for a form screen but can't seem to for this view all screen, perhaps  it's because it's a Listview.builder.

Thanks in advance.

Code below:

```
//class wide declaration
bool showSpinner = true;



Widget build(BuildContext context) {

ExpenseNotifier expenseNotifier = Provider.of<ExpenseNotifier>(context);


Future<void> _resfreshList() async {
  expenseNotifier.getExpenses(expenseNotifier);
}

    return Scaffold(
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
            inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
            child: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: _resfreshList,
              child: Consumer<ExpenseNotifier>(
                builder: (context, expense, child) {
                  return expense == null
                      ? Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            PaddingClass(bodyImage: 'images/empty.png'),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20.0,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'You don\'t have any expenses',
                              style: kLabelTextStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      : ListView.separated(
                          itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                            var myExpense = expense.expenseList[index];
                            return Card(
                              elevation: 8.0,
                              color: Colors.white70,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  RegularExpenseTextPadding(
                                    regText:
                                        '${_formattedDate(myExpense.updatedAt)}',
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: kThemeStyleBorderHighlightColour),
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 5,
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Text(
                                                '${myExpense.amount}',
                                                style: kRegularTextStyle,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 20.0,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                myExpense.description,
                                                style: kRegularTextStyle,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 1,
                                          child: GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              expenseNotifier.currentExpense =
                                                  expenseNotifier
                                                      .expenseList[index];
                                              Navigator.of(context).push(
                                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                                                      (BuildContext context) {
                                                return ExpenseDetailsScreen();
                                              }));
                                            },
                                            child: Icon(
                                              FontAwesomeIcons.caretDown,
                                              color: kThemeIconColour,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 20.0,
                            );
                          },
                          itemCount: expenseNotifier.expenseList.length,
                        );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
    }
```

Comment: This all sounds feasible. But it's going to be hard to help without seeing what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Hey Frank, I've edited my question to include my code.